# MPAndroidChart fading lines on line chart (step) when last two entries are close

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I have a simple line chart class that extends `com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart` with x-axis recording time (0-24) and Y-axis values from 1-4.

The first entry in the dataset will always have an x-value of 0 (carry over from previous day). When my last two entries are close together on the x-axis ( less than 1), the line on the graph fades near points and step. I have tried this on two devices, it is faulting on one (android api 17) and not the other (andorid api 18).

This issue disappears when the gap between the last two values increases or when I zoom in on the graph ~ (x100).

Dataset is configured as follows:

```
dataSet.setColor(-16222537);
dataSet.setDrawCircles(false);
dataSet.setDrawValues(false);
dataSet.setMode(LineDataSet.Mode.STEPPED);
dataSet.setDrawHighlightIndicators(false);
dataSet.setLineWidth(3);
```

The set of values I am plotting are

- (0, 1.0)
- (9.58333, 4.0)
- (9.73042, 4.0)

Screenshot of chart with fading lines:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`chart.setHardwareAccelerationEnabled(false);`

This should to the trick.

I've also noticed this on my Android 4.1 device.
Higher versions do not seem to have this issue, although I'm not sure from which version on.